# Will MongoDb authenticate against a database other than admin without a username and password?

Tags: mongodb

My goal is to understand user authentication against a MongoDb Standalone instance via connection string.

This document has been a great help but there are 2 cases that I'm confused on:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

I'm trying to ascertain if given these three permutations, can I build a valid connection string?

- Username
- Password
- Database Name

Where T is where the Username, Password, or Database is specified by the user and F when it is not:

```
Username Password Database Valid
T        T        T        T
T        T        F        ???
T        F        T        F
T        F        F        F
F        T        T        F
F        T        F        F
F        F        T        ???
F        F        F        T
```

I think that for the second case (T T F) I can substitute "admin" for the database name and then it'll have some chance of authenticating.

The second to last case (F F T) where the database is specified but not the user name or password is specified confuses me. If the "admin" database name is specified, then that's straightforward...but if it's other than "admin" can it EVER authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. T T F - if you substitute with 'admin' database, if the user was created in admin database, then the user will be authenticated else you will get authentication error
2. F F T - Whatever the database you specify, it will connect to the specified database, but you you cannot do any operation until you are authenticated using db.auth() command.